# Looking for language translation function for PHP

Tags: php, nlp, translation

I would like to add language translation to my site.  Is there any freeware (or at least inexpensive packages for a one-time fee) that will work more-or-less like this:

```
$french_text = translate ($german_text, 'german', 'french');
```

I don't expect it to support every language in the world, but to be useful it should at least support most European languages.  Also, being an English site, it's acceptable to me if it needs to use English as an intermediate language like this:

```
$english_text = translate ($german_text, 'german', english');
$french_text = translate ($english_text, 'english', 'french');
```

Does anything like this exist for PHP?

Comment: There's a related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302342/open-source-machine-translation-engines that includes a link to http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~mforcada/fosmt.html a page pointing to several free machine translation softwares.  None of them looks really plug-and-play though...

Comment: Haven't used it, but there is a google php api https://code.google.com/p/gtranslate-api-php/

Comment: Well, maybe if you let members in good standing post comments on any question to join in the discussion, PEOPLE WOULDN'T BE FORCED TO POST DUPLICATE QUESTIONS!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got mainly two options (that i know of, theres probably a ton more).

You've got PHPs [`intl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) stuff, or you can use the [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/)